# mysqldb programming Error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm getting an error trying to insert into a table using MySQLdb and can not figure it out.  I looked up how to catch the error but when I add the code to trap it, I don't get any additional info when I tried using raise e instead of print e and when I try print e I get an error.  I need some help getting the error to give me more detail.  I'll include the whole code in case someone is awesome enough to see where I went wrong in the first place.  Then I don't even care about the error trapping. Ok, yes I do because I am sure I will need it again soon. lol.  I actually have 8 columns I need to update.  I'm trying to use a process of elimination and only trying a couple at a time.  The ones like UPC, Name, and a couple others insert fine but Modl, Path, and Desc are causing errors.  Any help with either would be appreciated and thanks.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import MySQLdb
#from scrapy.extensions import DropItem
#from bff.items import ItemInfo

class mySQLPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        Product = item['ProdName']      
        Path = item['ProdPath']
        UPC = item['ProdUPC']
        Modl = item['ProdModel']
        Desc = item['ProdDesc']
        Price = item['ProdPrice']
        Stock = item['InStock']
        #Ships = item['Ships']
        Name = item['StoreName']
#Not Failing during insert    Product, Price, Stock, Name
#FAILing during insert   Modl, Path, Desc, 



        db = MySQLdb.connect(user='****', passwd='****',
                                      host='127.0.0.1',
                                      port=****,
                                      db='****')
        cursor = db.cursor()
 #       add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products (ProdName, StoreName) VALUES (%s, %s,)", Product, Name,)
 #       add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products, (ProdName)"
 #                      "VALUES (%s)", (Name))
 #                      "VALUES (%(Name)s)")
        add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products "
                        "(InStock, StoreName) "
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)")
                        #item['Ships'],

        data_Product = (Stock, Name)                                        

        #Add new product
        #try:
        cursor.execute(add_Product, data_Product)

        #except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, e: 
            #print e 

          # handle a specific error condition
        #except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            #raise e
          # handle a generic error condition
        #except MySQLdb.Warning, e:
            #print e        
          # handle warnings, if the cursor you're using raises them      
        #except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError, e:
            #print e

        # Make sure data is committed to the database
        db.commit()

        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return item
```

Comment: You put values in a list using `[]`, not `()`. `data_Product = [Stock, Name]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Barmar.  I gave that a try and was getting the same error.  I went back and replaced them with [] again like you said and am still getting the error.  pretty vague but here it it            
`ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'), ("\'http://www.godaddy.com/ip/5026447\'",))\' at line 1')`

Comment: That didn't work for me but Thanks for the reply.  I figured out what was happening.  It was actually a couple of things.  One a couple of them I had  the column set to varchar(200) and was getting over 2400 chars so increasing it fixed that.  On the URL on I wasn't escaping it and that was causing the errors.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. It was actually a couple of things. One a couple of them I had the column set to varchar(200) and was getting over 2400 chars so increasing it fixed that. On the URL on I wasn't escaping it and that was causing the errors. Thanks again. – Nick just now   edit

Comment: `Path = str(item['ProdPath'])
 Path = MySQLdb.escape_string(Path)`

Comment: Put it in the answer, not a comment.